# MessageHandler read message from socket from the middle and not from the beginning

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream

My `MessageHandler` receive message from socket. First of all it reads header (code of method `readMessageHeader()` is in the end of the post).
If header was read successfully, it reads message itself. The problem is that it starts reading header not from the beginning.
Here on the picture example of the message that `MassageHandler` received. Header and message are highlighted with blue colour.
`HEADER_MESSAGE_SIZE` is 20 bytes and it stores 5 integers. Header is fallowed by message.
So header should be:

`Var1 = 0x00000003`

`Var2 = 0x00000000`

`Var3 = 0x00000000`

`Var4 = 0x00000030`

`Var5 = 0x00000000`

[image: Message]

But from some reason MessageHandler started reading from the last line (line 00a0), and when he read 11 bytes, he reached end, and continued reading from the beginning. So finally he read:

`Var1 = 0x2D646973`

`Var2 = 0x636F6E6E`

`Var3 = 0x65637400` (`656374` are last 3 bytes of message and `00` is first byte of the message)

`Var4 = 0x00000300`

`Var5 = 0x00000000`

MessageHandler finishes reading successfully and return truth.

What coud be a reason of such behaviour? How can I fix it?

```
private boolean readMessageHeader() throws Exception{

        try {
            byte msg_bytes[]  = new byte[HEADER_MESSAGE_SIZE];

            // Read in the bytes
            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (offset < HEADER_MESSAGE_SIZE
                    && (numRead=dataInputStream.read(msg_bytes, offset, msg_bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }

            // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
            if (offset < HEADER_MESSAGE_SIZE) {
                if (offset==0){
                    LogUtils.info(thisClass, "socket peer closed" );
                } else {
                    LogUtils.warn(thisClass, "Failed to read header from socket" );
                }
                if (socket!=null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                    socket=null;
                }
                return false;
            }

            if(LogUtils.isDebugEnabled(this.getClass())) LogUtils.debug(thisClass, "Got new message"); 

            DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream(msg_bytes));         
            msgHead.readFromStream(reader);

            if(LogUtils.isDebugEnabled(this.getClass())) LogUtils.debug(thisClass, "message header: " + msgHead.toDebugString()); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtils.warn(thisClass, "Failed read msg header:" + e.getMessage());
            if (socket!=null){
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
                socket=null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

readMessageHeader() return truth.

Comment: Your function probably reads the end of one message and the beginning of another message. TCP is stream-based protocol, not record-based.

Comment: @AlexF, yes, I think you right. Thank you.